# React router dom cant find rest-like url

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So my website has articles, and user can research articles by location.

I would like to render the found articles at url : `/articles?location=:where`, but my router isn't able to find the route, and redirects me to `not-found`.

This is my BrowserRouter

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<AboutUs />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path="/publish-article" element={<WriteArticle />} />
      <Route path="/search-article" element={<Search />} />
      <Route path="/articles/:id" element={<RenderArticle />} />
      <Route path="/articles?location=:where" element={<ArticlesFound />} />
      <Route path="/quizz" element={<Quizz />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="/users/:username" element={<UserProfile />} />
      <Route path="/user-settings" element={<ProfileSettings />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Does any body know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `*` means all so it will always redirect to NotFound

Comment: no, because it's the last route, so the default case. All my other routes work. except `articles?location=:where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont setup routes for URL SearchParams, you just extract it in the component like

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
searchParams.get("location");
```

at least in react router v6

Comment: how can I extract the url params if my router renders the wrong component

Comment: In my opinion your REST-Like API is wrong, if you want to render different Components by SearchParams. I simply would add an if statement to the component which is rendered by "/articles". If no location-SearchParam is set, render all, etc..

Comment: Do you mean to add the following route : `/articles*`? and then parse the params ?

Comment: Ye, i would replace ```path="/articles?location=:where"``` with ```path="/articles"```

Comment: did you not add the `*` at the end of your route on purpose ? because I can"t get how the router will find the route containing the query string else. For me `/articles` is to render all the articles, and `/articles?location=paris` to render articles in Paris

Comment: whatever mate, I got it thank you